# excel sheet won't save any new changes

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

i'm manipulating an excel file through visual studio
i use the saveAs method to save the workbook but when i try to modify the excel worksheet later (directly) and close the excel file it doesn't save the changes and i have to do it manually by pressing ctrl+s 
can any body help me figrue it out 
thanks..
this is the code i use to save my excel file in c#`

```
mWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what library your using? I'm also intrigued by `xlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange`

Comment: Does look like Excel interop, but yes please be specific.

Comment: When are you calling that?

Comment: @dckuehn: `XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange` means don't change the current file access mode.

Comment: When I used to manipulate Excel files from C# using Interop, the file was never visible. Could it be that you have one copy of Excel running with the file open and your C# code creates a separate copy? Look at your process list and see if you have Excel.exe running twice. If you can limit yourself to the newer .xlsx format, have a serious look at EPPlus. It's open source and far easier to use.

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; this is the library that i'm using..

Comment: i'm calling that at the end after storing the data in the wrokbook